# experimental nvidia drivers, no normal boot? how to remove nvidia drivers from recovery mode?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uninstall, recovery-mode

After I installed experimental Nvidia drivers, Ubuntu will not boot. How can I remove the drivers from recovery mode?

If I choose recovery mode and in the menu choose "root" (drop to root shell prompt), and then try to use the command `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`

it says:

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/thakang/console: read-only file system

W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock  
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/ 
E: the package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have used `login` and logged in so my shell now shows `:~$`

Thank you

Comment: possibly related: [about stalling fsck in recovery mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240527/is-recovery-mode-supposed-to-hang-after-fsck/240535#240535).

Answer (score 4):

You need to mount your system first in read/write mode:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```