# How can I install unity from recovery mode?

Tags: installation, recovery-mode

My computer crashed and my desktop does not load up and I have no terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> etc, so I uninstalled compiz from root shell prompt.

This has removed unity so now I need to re-install it in recovery mode:

`apt-get install unity` returns `not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Answer (score 0):

You probably face the problem that everything is mounted read-only in the recovery-system. Please see [my answer to "Is recovery mode supposed to hang..."](https://askubuntu.com/a/240535/117103) about how to work around that.